# Custom 'Who's Online' View - How to filter User View by whether logged in

Tags: views

I have a User View that is trying to replicate the 'who's online' block. It currently has 3 filters:

- A custom user_profile field (Must be **False**)
- User: Active (Yes)
- User: Current (Yes)

For some reason the filter works on when using the first two but when I introduce the User: Current filter it filters the entire view by the active user.

What I need to do is be able to filter the view by **all** current logged in users.

Comment: Active user simply means if they are blocked or not, it doesn't determine if they are online or offline.

Comment: Any ideas how to filter by online/offline?

Comment: 'User: Current' is the person that views the view. In other words, if Peter views the view, only Peter will be listed.

Comment: You could try to achieve it by adding a User: Last access filter and setting it to -2 minutes or so.

Answer (score 1):

You need the [User Stats](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_stats) module.

> Provides commonly requested user statistics for themers, IP address tracking and Views integration. Statistics are:
>
> - days registered;
>   -join date;
> - days since last login;
> - days since last post;
> - post count;
> - login count;
> - user online/offline;
> - IP address;

Once you install this module, you will get an option online user as filter. That's it.